# How do you re-map a numpad?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've got an independent numpad, a keyboard, which also has a numpad, and a drawing tablet connected to my desktop. I'd like to re-map the independent numpad, but not the numpad on my main keyboard, and use  it to supplement the keys on my drawing tablet.

I've looked at how to create a custom keyboard layout, but I'd like to be able to remap every single key, including enter, backspace, etc. and I'd like to set shortcuts like ctrl+z to a single key.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Should be possible so long as X detects key presses from the numpad.

You'll need `xev` which you'll get by installing `x11-utils`.

The process is defined quite well here: 
http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Configuring_keyboards#Enabling_Keyboard_Multimedia_Keys

Effectively you'll use `xev` to capture keycodes from the numpad and use `xmodmap` to map key presses (and releases) to functions.

There's also heap of great information here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap

Note: I will not be suprised if Wayland has issues with this approach, so watch out for that and be prepared for a need to switch to Xorg (which is trivial).